# sklearn's leave-one-out on a DataFrame object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn

I'm pretty new with coding and I got a school project where I have to work with datasets in Python with Pandas and Sklearn. The problem is that I have a pandas dataframe that I need to split, using leave-one-out crossvalidation (because of only 140 people in the DataFrame)

Edit: As said by @FChm , I used the documentation for LeaveOneOut from sklearn. Linked here: [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html)

```
import pandas as pd 
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np

data = pd.read_csv('model_2.csv')

X = data.iloc[:,0:11]
y = data.loc[:,'Diagnosis']
loo = LeaveOneOut()

print(X)
print(y)
print(type(X))

for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X): # Split in X
    print("TRAIN:", train_index, "TEST:", test_index)
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
    print(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
model = LogisticRegression(solver='lbfgs', multi_class='auto' )
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
z = model.score(X_test, y_test)
print (z)
```

The problem is that slicing the columns is giving me a dataframe back and the error message that I get is:

```
Fusobacterium nucleatum [1480]             ...               Bilophila wadsworthia [756]
0                          0.000000             ...                                  0.001307
1                          0.000617             ...                                  0.000779
2                          0.000000             ...                                  0.000474
3                          0.000000             ...                                  0.000660
4                          0.000025             ...                                  0.001572
5                          0.000000             ...                                  0.000881
6                          0.000000             ...                                  0.000175
7                          0.000000             ...                                  0.000141
8                          0.000181             ...                                  0.000778
9                          0.000000             ...                                  0.011267
10                         0.000962             ...                                  0.002417
11                         0.000011             ...                                  0.000618
12                         0.000000             ...                                  0.001590
13                         0.000001             ...                                  0.004002
14                         0.000000             ...                                  0.000650
15                         0.000029             ...                                  0.007482
16                         0.000000             ...                                  0.001184
17                         0.000000             ...                                  0.001821
18                         0.000045             ...                                  0.000768
19                         0.000000             ...                                  0.000003
20                         0.000182             ...                                  0.001198
21                         0.000000             ...                                  0.004408
22                         0.000000             ...                                  0.003469
23                         0.000000             ...                                  0.002255
24                         0.000292             ...                                  0.000174
25                         0.000000             ...                                  0.002559
26                         0.000000             ...                                  0.000901
27                         0.000015             ...                                  0.000458
28                         0.000045             ...                                  0.000009
29                         0.000437             ...                                  0.000834
..                              ...             ...                                       ...
111                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000000
112                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000234
113                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000190
114                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000048
115                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000792
116                        0.000000             ...                                  0.001992
117                        0.000010             ...                                  0.000000
118                        0.000108             ...                                  0.001133
119                        0.000000             ...                                  0.001465
120                        0.000000             ...                                  0.005596
121                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000284
122                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000037
123                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000008
124                        0.000000             ...                                  0.001098
125                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000179
126                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000309
127                        0.000030             ...                                  0.001022
128                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000060
129                        0.000002             ...                                  0.000795
130                        0.000000             ...                                  0.002253
131                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000048
132                        0.000000             ...                                  0.001198
133                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000755
134                        0.000011             ...                                  0.001414
135                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000739
136                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000000
137                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000275
138                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000330
139                        0.000000             ...                                  0.055944
140                        0.000000             ...                                  0.000531

[141 rows x 11 columns]
0             Cancer
1             Cancer
2             Cancer
3             Cancer
4             Cancer
5             Cancer
6             Cancer
7             Cancer
8             Cancer
9             Cancer
10            Cancer
11            Cancer
12            Cancer
13            Cancer
14            Cancer
15            Cancer
16            Cancer
17            Cancer
18            Cancer
19            Cancer
20            Cancer
21            Cancer
22            Cancer
23            Cancer
24            Cancer
25            Cancer
26            Cancer
27            Cancer
28            Cancer
29            Cancer
           ...
111           Normal
112           Normal
113           Normal
114    Small Adenoma
115    Small Adenoma
116    Small Adenoma
117    Small Adenoma
118    Small Adenoma
119    Small Adenoma
120    Small Adenoma
121    Small Adenoma
122    Small Adenoma
123    Small Adenoma
124    Small Adenoma
125    Small Adenoma
126    Small Adenoma
127    Small Adenoma
128    Small Adenoma
129    Small Adenoma
130    Small Adenoma
131    Small Adenoma
132    Small Adenoma
133    Small Adenoma
134    Small Adenoma
135    Small Adenoma
136    Small Adenoma
137    Small Adenoma
138    Small Adenoma
139    Small Adenoma
140    Small Adenoma
Name: Diagnosis, Length: 141, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
TRAIN: [  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18
  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36
  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54
  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72
  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90
  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126
 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140] TEST: [0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\model.py", line 19, in <module>
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2682, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_array(key)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2726, in _getitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Users\Chris\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: '[  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18\n  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36\n  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54\n  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72\n  73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90\n  91  92  93  94  95  96  97  98  99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108\n 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126\n 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140] not in index'
```

Is there a way to use leave-one-out on a Pandas DataFrame, or should I use train_test_split? And how could I use this like a leave-one-out behaviour.

Comment: Please do not use the comments space for such kind of additional info - edit & update your post instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error is because you are indexing the DataFrames incorrectly (i.e., you are treating them as arrays). This is probably because you copied the example from the documentation without fully understanding it. Note: If you did directly copy from the [documentation for LeaveOneOut](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html) you really should directly reference it at least saying: 'I adapted the code from here ...'

Anyway, you have two solutions to fix your problem:

**a)** You could convert your `X` and `y` to numpy arrays by using the [to_numpy()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy) method of a pd.DataFrame:

```
X = data.iloc[:, 0:11].to_numpy()
y = data.loc[:, 'Diagnosis'].to_numpy()
```

**b)** You could change your code and index your code using [integer based indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) (as you do in our first few lines).

```
X_train = X.iloc[train_index, :]
# … and so on
```

Comment: Thanks, both ways did the job! Cheers @FChm

Comment: Great glad to hear it! Please consider accepting the answer if it addressed your question.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same question and used the code:

```
X = X.values
y = y.values
```

And it works fine for me.